# Localize UIDatePicker in CountDownTimer mode

Tags: ios, uikit, interface-builder, uidatepicker

I'm using a UIDatePicker in CountDownTimer mode and would like it to be localized. I.e. having the hour(s) and minute(s) labels to display other languages.

As I understand from the documentation of UIDatePicker, I assume that all it takes is setting the locale property in IB to "Default", but I guess I'm wrong as the labels don't change when changing language on the device.

If it is not possible, I guess the best solution is either subclass UIDatePicker and insert properly localized labels above the hour/minute labels, or making my own from scratch by subclassing UIPickerView (although that seem to be a lot of work).

Anyone that can enlighten me on how to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly after posting this, I realized that CFBundleDevelopmentRegion was set to "en". Note to self: Check Info.plist.

Answer (score -1):

self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
self.datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 180.0f); // set frame as your need
self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
[self.view addSubview: self.datePicker];

Comment: I don't see that this is relevant to the question